# Filternig Sensordata from DynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-dynamodb

i'm reading sensor-data from dynamoDB with use of Boto3.
Everything works fine except two issues:

1. My Partition-Key (time) gets listed on second position of my data instead of the beginning
2. How am I able to filter the lines for certain time values (f.x. Data form 23/8/2021 16.XX o.Clock? Like shown in the picture [Sensor Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwKMG.png) it shows all data values.  in the wrong order

Thanks in advance!

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('ProjektarbeitTable')
items = table.scan()['Items']

for item in items:
    print (item)
```

Comment: On #1, why is the ordering of the keys in the print out of the returned dictionary important to you? On #2, write a scan with a filter expression, and sort the returned data any way you want to with a custom sort (client-side). Note: for large tables, scan may be inefficient and you should consider reviewing your table indexes and issue a query instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! 

"Zeit = '23/8/2021 15:11:40'
items = table.scan(FilterExpression=(Attr("time").eq(Zeit)))['Items']"
has worked. But is there any way to use placeholders for the time so that i get all data from 23/8/2021?
Since I'm a beginner with python I wasn't able to do it the right way. 

And for the first question: It's more useful for me to have the time in the first column for a chronological order.

Comment: Python 3.7 and later guarantees insertion-order preservation of keys in dictionaries, however you are receiving these dicts from the boto3 SDK and it did not insert the keys in the order you want. If you really need this, either populate a replacement dict with `time` first, or create a custom `print` function that prints the items in the order you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict your table scan to those items with certain attribute values, you can supply a [filter expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression).

Python 3.7 and later guarantees insertion-order preservation of keys in dictionaries, however you are receiving these dicts from the boto3 SDK and it did not insert the keys in the order you want. If you really need this, either populate a replacement dict with time first, or create a custom print function that prints the items in the order you prefer.

To filter on the date part of a timestamp string such as '23/8/2021 15:11:40', you can supply a [filter expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) using begins_with, and match on just the initial date substring.